# I can't receiving Messages in Postman from WebSocket in Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, postman

My configuration of WebSocket the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gamepoint");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app").enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

In controller I send a message to the topic

```
 @PostMapping("/connect")
    public ResponseEntity<Game> connect (@RequestBody ConnectRequest connectRequest) {
        Optional<Game> optionalGame = gameService.connectToGame(connectRequest.getGameId(),
                connectRequest.getPlayer());
        if (optionalGame.isPresent()) {
            ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            executor.schedule(() -> simpMessagingTemplate.
                    convertAndSend("/topic/game-process/" + optionalGame.get().getGameId(), 1),DELAY_START, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            executor.shutdown();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(optionalGame.get());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
```

**optionalGame.get().getGameId() - GUID*

In Postman I successfully connect to WebSocket:
ws://localhost:8080/gamepoint

How I can get messages in Postman from server using method SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend()?

Unfortunately, I could not find any infomation.

Comment: please try `/app/gamepoint`